# Node.JS AES decryption truncates initial result

Tags: node.js, encryption, cryptography

I'm attempting to replicate some python encryption code in node.js using the built in crypto library.  To test, I'm encrypting the data using the existing python script and then attempting to decrypt using node.js.

I have everything working except for one problem, doing the decryption results in a truncated initial decrypted result unless I grab *extra* data, which then results in a truncated final result.

I'm very new to the security side of things, so apologize in advance if my vernacular is off.

Python encryption logic:

```
encryptor = AES.new(key, AES.MODE_CBC, IV)
<# Header logic, like including digest, salt, and IV #>
for rec in vect:
            chunk = rec.pack()  # Just adds disparate pieces of data into a contiguous bytearray of length 176
            encChunk = encryptor.encrypt(chunk)
            outfile.write(encChunk)
```

Node decryption logic:

```
let offset = 0;
let derivedKey = crypto.pbkdf2Sync(secret, salt, iterations, 32, 'sha256');
let decryptor = crypto.createDecipheriv('aes-256-cbc', derivedKey, iv);
let chunk = data.slice(offset, (offset + RECORD_LEN))
while(chunk.length > 0) {
    let clearChunk = decryptor.update(chunk);
    // unpack clearChunk and do something with that data
    offset += RECORD_LEN;
    chunk = data.slice(offset, offset + RECORD_LEN);
}
```

I would expect my initial result to print something like this to hex:

```
54722e34d8b2bf158db6b533e315764f87a07bbfbcf1bd6df0529e56b6a6ae0f123412341234123400000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000
```

And it gets close, expect it cuts off the final 16 bytes (in example above the final 32 "0's" would be missing).  This shifts all following decryptions by those 16 bytes, meaning those 32 "0's" are added to the front of the next decrypted chunk.

If I add 16 bytes to the initial chunk size (meaning actually grab *more* data, not just shift the offset) then this solves everything on the front end, but results in the final chunk losing it's last 16 bytes of data.

One thing that seems weird to me: The initial chunk has a length of 176, but the decrypted results has a length of 160.  All other chunks have lengths 176 before and after decryption.  I'm assuming I'm doing something wrong with how I'm initializing the decryptor which is causing it to expect an extra 16 bytes of data at the beginning, but can't for the life of me figure out what.

I must be close since the decrypted data is correct, minus the mystery shifting, even when reading in large amounts of data.  Just need to figure out this final step.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Short version based on your updated code: if you are absolutely certain that every block will be 176 bytes (i.e. a multiple of 16), then you can add `cipher.setAutoPadding(false)` to your Node code. If that's not true, or for more about why, read on.

---

At the end of your decryption, you need to call `decryptor.final` to get the final block.

If you have all the data together, you can decrypt it in one call:

```
let clearChunk = decryptor.update(chunk) + decryptor.final()
```

`update()` exists so that you can pass data to the decryptor in chunks. For example, if you had a very large file, you may not want a full copy of the encrypted data plus a full copy of the decrypted data in memory at the same time. You can therefore read encrypted data from the file in chunks, pass it to `update()`, and write out the decrypted data in chunks.

The input data using CBC mode must be a multiple of 16 bytes long. To ensure this, we typically use PKCS7 padding. That will pad out your input data to a multiple of 16. If it's already a multiple of 16 it will add an extra block of 16 bytes. The padding value is the number of padding values. So if your block is 12 bytes long, it will be padded with 04040404. If it's a multiple of 16, then the padding is 16 bytes of 0x10. This padding system lets the decryptor validate that it's removing the right amount of padding. This is likely what's causing your 176/160 issue.

This padding issue is why there's a `final()` call. The system needs to know which block is the last block so it can remove the padding. So the first call to `update()` will always return one fewer blocks than you pass in, since it's holding onto it until it knows whether it's the last block.

---

Looking at your Python code, I think it's not padding at all (most Python libraries I'm familiar with don't pad automatically). As long as the input is certain to be a multiple of 16, that's ok. But the default for Node is to expect padding. If you know that your size will always be a multiple of 16, then you can change the Node side with `cipher.setAutoPadding(false)`. If you don't know for certain that the input size will *always* be a multiple of 16, then you need to add a `pad()` call on the Python side for the final block.

Comment: You are a king among men!  Setting auto padding to false fixed it.  The input size is guaranteed to always be a multiple of 16, as each encrypted input is hard set to a size of 176.  This seems like the simplest fix, and seems pretty safe as the same tool will be used to encrypt and decrypt the files moving forward.  Any reason why auto-padding shouldn't be set to false, other than to guard against possibly having input that isn't a multiple of 16?

Comment: If you control both sides of the system and you know your data size, there's no need to add padding. Padding is normal (because it's needed for arbitrary input sizes), but it doesn't add any security. There are even well known padding attacks, so in most cases you're technically going to be a bit more secure without it.